# Is it possible to share asp.net mvc sessions between machines?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis

I want my website to be able to overcome servers crashes by sharing the open sessions between several machines.

How can i accomplish that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [Out-of-Process Session State](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754032%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> Out-of-process session state mode preserves session state data by
>   running outside the worker processes where ASP.NET applications are
>   running. Use one of the following configurations to maintain
>   out-of-process session state:
>
> - A state server, which depends on the Windows state service, Aspnet_state.exe, to store session state data
> - A SQL Server database